# Outward normal vector on a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Given a simple *closed* curve $\gamma:[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^2}, \gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ and a point $P(x, y) = \gamma(t)$ for some $t \in [a,b]$, it is known that two normal unit vectors exist for $P$, which can be found by solving:

$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{n}\cdot\gamma'(t)=0\\
||\mathbf{n}||=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$

Let the solutions be $\mathbf{n_1}$ and $\mathbf{n_2}$ with $\mathbf{n_1} = -\mathbf{n_2}$. Can one algebraically decide which of these unit vectors points outwards, i.e., without having to resort to plotting the curve and analyzing it?

Comment: Presumably you assume here that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are more than continuous? They must be at least differentiable for the normal to be well defined, though of course $C^n$ or $C^\infty$ would be more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way (among many), provided certain differentiability assumptions, though strictly speaking it involves calculus as well as algebra. One can ask if the velocity sweeps out a circle in the direction of the normal or in the opposite direction.

For the unit normal to be well defined and unique up to sign, the unit tangent vector $\mathbf{u}(t)=\dot{\gamma}(t)/\|\dot{\gamma}(t)\|$ has to exist everywhere. If $\mathbf{u}$ is differentiable, we can define the angular velocity function with respect to a particular choice of normal.
$$
\omega(t)=\dot{\mathbf{u}}(t)\cdot\mathbf{n}(t)
$$
It can then be shown (for a *simple* curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$) that
$$
\int_a^b\omega(t)dt=\begin{cases}2\pi & \mathbf{n}\ \ \text{inward} \\ -2\pi & \mathbf{n} \ \ \text{outward} \end{cases}
$$
Computing this quantity allows one to identify the two normals.